# Boogie on Visual Studio

Tags: z3, dafny

My question is about Boogie, but since no Boogie tag was available, I  used the dafny tag as one that is closely related to Boogie.

I have built Boogie on Visual Studio following the instructions in the documentation. What should I do next to write Boogie code or equivalently how can I run the .bpl files in the Test folder?  From what I understood is that Boogie although an intermediate verification language can be used independently as well.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no interactive VS mode for Boogie.  If you want to write Boogie code and get design-time feedback in the editor, then the best mode available is in emacs, see https://github.com/boogie-org/boogie-friends.  Still, this emacs mode does not give you error traces or verification-debugger information.

Comment: Thanks, I have already set up boogie-friends on emacs, and was looking for something similar on VS. Am I correct to assume that the feature on on emacs where you can see the translated dafny code is not available on VS?

Answer (score 0):

Boogie depends on [Z3](https://github.com/Z3Prover), so make sure that's available.

Then, from the command line:

- `boogie.exe /help`
- `boogie.exe file_to_verify.bpl`

Comment: Thanks, I run it from the command line, how can I do that from Visual Studio? How can I see those verification traces from VS? Syntax highlighting and the rest.

Comment: No idea, sorry.